# Problems in generating a proper qr-code using zxing

Tags: java, qr-code, zxing

i have a problem in generating proper qr-codes with the zxing api.
I am able to generate a qr-code but when i read the qr-code then chars like "äü" arent displayed right.

code:

```
BitMatrix matrix = writer.encode(text, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 200,200);
//text is String text = "geändert";

bufferedImage = MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(matrix);
```

If i start with "ü" then followed by "äö" then its displayed correct
anyone knows why?

Comment: Are you certain that it's the QR code which is wrong and not whatever you're using to decode it?

Comment: yes i have alredy tried 3 qr code "reader" on the iphone

Comment: I wrote an answer using `zxing` to generate the QR code in [Stack Overflow: qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786226/qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport/47383846#47383846). If suits your requirement you can use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can read the QR Code from zxing api from below code.

```
binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("QR_Code.JPG")))));
        result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap);
        System.out.println("QR Code : "+result.getText());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the developer documentation from zxing http://code.google.com/p/zxing/wiki/DeveloperNotes you will see that they expressly talk about the issue with non latin based characters.

As the QR Code standard does not define an exact way of specificing the character encoding within a QR code there recommendation is to only use characters which appear within all three standard encodings (ISO-8859-1, ISO-8859-15, UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

In the `Hashtable` of hints that you pass the encoder, set `EncoderHintType.CHARACTER_SET` to `"UTF-8"`. Barry's answer is correct, but forcing it to try UTF-8 might happen to work better for you.

Comment: thank you sean for the hint with the hash table!! i also had to add a UTF-8 BOM to the string, but now it works! many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read the QR Code from zxing api from below code.

```
binaryBitmap = new BinaryBitmap(new HybridBinarizer(new BufferedImageLuminanceSource(ImageIO.read(new FileInputStream("QR_Code.JPG"))))); 

result = new MultiFormatReader().decode(binaryBitmap); 

System.out.println("QR Code : "+result.getText());
```