# QR Code integration in jasperReport

Tags: jasper-reports, qr-code

I am generating the JasperReport for my billing desktop application using JAVA but, I can't see the QR Code icon in the report in jasper 6.0.3 version; In the preview it is showing the QR Code, but not in the real report.

Please can anyone suggest the idea and QR Code JAR files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer for this question,

We need to use the jar files to import the inbuilt jasperReport QR Code
These are the jar files to generate the QR Code with Jasper report.

[image]

Also this jar files working for the jasper report without any exceptions.

then we have to drag and drop the QR-Code from the jasper report Elements. and then we can define specified parameters using the xml.

```
       <componentElement>
            <reportElement x="547" y="-5" width="115" height="83" uuid="f5bf25f8-2967-4e4e-bfa2-7879a3275e1c"/>
            <jr:QRCode xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["Customer No: " + $F{CUST_NO}]]></jr:codeExpression>
            </jr:QRCode>
        </componentElement>
```

Its working for me.

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 70; columnNumber: 236; cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'jr:QRCode'. One of '{"http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports":component}' is expected.

Comment: I am also getting same error. is there any solution?

Answer (score 24):

I am writing my answer very late. But I think **zxing** is the best open source library for generating the QR code. Here I am writing how you can generate QR code using zxing library in Java. I am using iReport as designer tool.

Step 1: Add 2 jar files in class path of iReport (**Tools** > **Options** > **iReport Tab** > **Classpath Tab** > **Add Jar**)

a) `zxing-core` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/3.3.1

b) `zxing-javase` from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/javase/3.3.1

*Note: You may choose latest jar's. I am using latest as of date*

[Screen shot of adding jar in class path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkOM9.png)

Step 2: Create a parameter / field (as per your need). I am using a parameter. Let us call it **qrCode**.

Step 3: Drag and drop an image from palette panel of iReport designer (In windows it is accessible through `Shift + ctrl + 8`). And choose **Cancel** (We do not want static image).

Step 4: Select the image by clicking on it. You will see the properties tab in right side.

a) Choose **Expression Class** as **java.awt.Image**

b) Click on **Image Expression** property. And fill the expression as

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
    new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
        $P{qrCode},
        com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300
    )
)
```

*Note: If you want to use `field` instead of `parameter` just replace the `parameter` with `field` in expression.*

[Screen shot of steps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAZIP.png)

Step 5: Compile report and run.

*To read about different usage go through the post [Generate QR code in Java using zxing](https://www.callicoder.com/generate-qr-code-in-java-using-zxing/)*

Comment: what is $P{qrCode} parameter data type? is it string?

Comment: @Julius Prayogo yes it is of `java.lang.String` datatype.

Comment: To avoid `Found empty contents` error you can set the image Print When Expression to `$P{qrCode} != null && $P{qrCode}.length() > 0`

Comment: I'm getting this error: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRImageLoader.getInstance(Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/JasperReportsContext;)Lnet/sf/jasperreports/engine/util/JRImageLoader; at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.RenderableUtil.getRenderable(RenderableUtil.java:173)`