# Encoding QR Code with UTF-8 as an image on JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports, zxing

I tried to encode some text on languages such as Vietnamese, Russian to QR Code in JasperReports following this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29786226/qr-code-integration-in-jasperreport).

I'm using Zxing API. It's working ok for EN, US locales, but I faced issue with encoding text in Russian or Vietnamese.

I used this expression:

```
    com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
        new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
   "французкий язык",
            com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300
        )
    )
```

The result of decoding is: `?????????? ????`

How to fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this way worked for me.

```
com.google.zxing.client.j2se.MatrixToImageWriter.toBufferedImage(
    new com.google.zxing.qrcode.QRCodeWriter().encode(
       new String(("французкий язык").getBytes("UTF-8"), "ISO-8859-1"),
        com.google.zxing.BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE, 300, 300
    )
)
```